# How to properly follow a forked git repository?

Tags: git

We have to fork a repository and keep it up to date, with adding changes here and there. The important branches are remote/1.0 and remote/1.1

The workflow currently used is to fork the repository, create our own 1.0 branch that is the same as remote/1.0. Changes are then made that are pushed to our 1.0. Now, we have to create a new 1.1 branch based on our 1.0 and merge remote/1.1 to it. The idea is to end up with the copy of remote/1.1 branch, but with all our previous changes kept (where that made sense, some changes may have to be adjusted to remote/1.1).

Is merging every so often a correct strategy here? Or should rebasing be more appropriate? Is a better third way to do it?

Comment: For me your question boils down to *is rebase better than merge?* I would always *rebase* my changes ontop of `remote/1.1` (which I assume is the "bleading edge" or `develop` branch according the [standard branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: You mentioned "We have forked" — I assume you are working on a team? This is significant if you are thinking about debasing commits.

Comment: Are you planning on merging your fork into their repository? If so, how often? What is their pull request process?

Comment: Yes, I'm part of a team. Shouldn't rebase be fine if it produces a new branch (i.e. no rebasing of pushed commits)? The fork is never going to be merged.